# Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity

Tags: android, image, camera, capture

I want to write a module where on a click of a button the camera opens and I can click and capture an image.  If I don't like the image I can delete it and click one more image and then select the image and it should return back and display that image in the activity.

Comment: you should open a camera intent, capture an image, save it on SDcard if want to, take an id through content provider, display it in dialog box with ok/cancel button.

Comment: @jengelsma i have one problem using camera i capture image in portraite mode and display in imageview then it's always display in landscape mode.have you nay idea?else can u slove this issue.plz reply i wait your answer.

Comment: @Harsha M V if u got the answer then reply me.

Comment: **This Blog Can help you.**  http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/10/importing-image-from-camera.html

Comment: Refer the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977245/android-open-camera-from-button/40041381#40041381

Comment: Refer this Blog, http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.com/2018/06/capture-image-using-fileprovider.html

Comment: Related sample from CommonsWare: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider

Comment: @jengelsma                mImageBitmap = rotateBitmap(mImageBitmap, 90);

Answer (score 525, accepted):

Here's an example activity that will launch the camera app and then retrieve the image and display it.

```
package edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }  
    } 
}
```

Note that the camera app itself gives you the ability to review/retake the image, and once an image is accepted, the activity displays it.

Here is the layout that the above activity uses.  It is simply a LinearLayout containing a Button with id button1 and an ImageView with id imageview1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/photo"></Button>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And one final detail, be sure to add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```

and if camera is optional to your app functionality. make sure to set require to false in the permission. like this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

to your manifest.xml.

Comment: Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  Its giving a Null pointer expection. When i open the app and click Capture.. it goes to the camera app and after 2-4 secs the whole thing crashes.

Comment: I suppose to be on the safe side we should be checking to see if resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK in the onActivityResult() method.  As to why the camera is crashing, we'd have to see a stack trace.

Comment: @Harsha M V This is a known bug on Samsung Galaxy. Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031374/photo-capture-intent-causes-nullpointerexception-on-samsung-phones-only/7031422#7031422

Comment: This link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html states it also needs <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />. I can understand it needs that permission, however does it really need the <uses-feature>s? I imagine the Play Store would filter out devices with no camera when u use those, however what if using the camera in your app is optional? You would lose a lot of potential users if it does filters out devices with no camera.

Comment: @WillKru if the feature is not mandatory, you should add the `<uses-feature/>` with the `android:required="false"` attribute: `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"></uses-feature> `

Comment: @Mannaz hey can u tell me how to open both camrea and galerry in onclick?i have done but dont view both of at one popup.have u any idea ?

Comment: @jengelsma onActivityResult is not getting called...? i am using your code first it was calling but next day i tried since then onActivityResult is not calling...

Comment: data gives only thumbnail image

Comment: FAIL - it takes image but it does not show the image correctly like it gets flipped or inverted or rotated.

Comment: I was wondering whether anybody could expand on this answer. Thanks for what is posted originally as that is great. Although I want a way to be able to have a way to constantly save any image taken using the Camera Intent in my app. I want to display them in a GridView. Currently, when I close the app and re-open it, the images all disappear! Thanks in advance. Even a post to an answer or tutorial would be helpful!

Comment: @jengelsma i had used this code it capturing image and displaing propertly but it will cause other problem that it will remove old data from other control like i had selected in spinter then it will recreate activity and clear all data. can you check it?

Comment: Looks like `data` is also null on Nexus 4 devices, possibly other Google devices as well.

Comment: Also note that `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); ` does not grab the image that was taken. It grabs a thumbnail of the image that was taken.

Comment: Works perfect, how could you enable cropping so it has to be square before it returns to the app?

Comment: Works perfectly - also with fragments

Comment: @BillyCoover, do you know a way on displaying the actual image instead of just the thumbnail? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question, in your code example you use the package `edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo`, I tried to do the same, but in my case IDE doesn't recognize it. Hence, how can I add this package to SDK/IDE?

Comment: It working fine. But how to capture high resolution image?

Comment: android.hardware.camera is now deprecated

Comment: App crashes when you press X on Camera

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It captures low resolution thumbnail, not the actual photo.

Comment: You need this permission too <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: To check all permission needed I suggest you to check this page: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera)

Comment: If you want to save the actual image from the camera use
`Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/flashCropped.png"));
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivityForResult(camera, 1);`

you need to save the file first in your app media storage then you can able to save actual image.

Answer (score 95):

## Update (2020)

Google has added a new [`ActivityResultRegistry`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultRegistry) API that *"lets you handle the `startActivityForResult()` + `onActivityResult()` as well as `requestPermissions()` + `onRequestPermissionsResult()` flows without overriding methods in your Activity or Fragment, brings increased type safety via `ActivityResultContract`, and provides hooks for testing these flows"* - [source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.2.0-alpha02).

The API was added in [androidx.activity 1.2.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.2.0-alpha02) and [androidx.fragment 1.3.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02).

So you are now able to do something like:

```
val takePicture = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { success: Boolean ->
    if (success) {
        // The image was saved into the given Uri -> do something with it
    }
}

val imageUri: Uri = ...
button.setOnClickListener {
    takePicture.launch(imageUri)
}
```

Take a look at the documentation to learn how to use the new Activity result API: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#kotlin

There are many built-in [ActivityResultContracts](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts) that allow you to do different things like pick contacts, request permissions, take pictures or take videos. You are probably interested in the [ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture) shown above.

Note that [androidx.fragment 1.3.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha04) deprecates the `startActivityForResult()` + `onActivityResult()` and `requestPermissions()` + `onRequestPermissionsResult()` APIs on Fragment. Hence it seems that `ActivityResultContracts` is the new way to do things from now on.

---

## Original answer (2015)

It took me some hours to get this working. The code it's almost a copy-paste from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), with a minor difference.

Request this permission on the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

On your `Activity`, start by defining this:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private ImageView mImageView;
```

Then fire this `Intent` in an `onClick`:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Add the following support method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  // prefix
            ".jpg",         // suffix
            storageDir      // directory
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Then receive the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            mImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What made it work is the `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath))`, which is different from the code from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). The original code gave me a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: "Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath))" is the solution since MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT leads to null intent result.

Comment: My picture is coming in landscape mode by default, am I missing anything?

Comment: I am using this in a FragmentDialog and it crashes on this line: startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE); with this error:java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.lge.camera/.app.CameraActivity clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20170721_040943_-644534083.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{65edf85 19134:com.devhopes.ryde/u0a151} (pid=19134, uid=10151) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA - when I click on the image view

Comment: @LizG you need to request permissions to use the camera on Android 6.0 and above.

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo other than adding them to AndroidManifest, how can I do that?

Comment: @LizG you have to request permissions at run time. It's explained in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Great to see that you followed Android recommendations.

Comment: This code didn't work for me. I receive `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20180823_102340_722874009725833047.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()`. Any idea on how to fix this? @AlbertVilaCalvo

Comment: @RobertGomez you can no longer use `file: Uri` values in many places. See this blog post from Mark Murphy: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo I didn't know that. So, do you have any idea about how to fix this? I don't know what can I change. I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: I had to use `storageDir = Context.getFilesDir();` in place of File `storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`. Otherwise I was getting a permission denied error.

Comment: Struggled a long time before i saw "file:" in the path. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: You need to add storage permission for API 23+ even if you have added permission in Manifest.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41220767/8330249

Comment: This updated answer is just valid to Kotlin? I can't find Java example

Comment: startActivityForResult is deprecated

Comment: This is a great solution if you do not need a Camera permission in any other part of the app. If you add CAMERA permission in manifest. This will not work. Atleast, I could not get it working as of today. I needed CAMERA permission for MLKit barcode analysis too for example.

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117511/exposed-beyond-app-through-clipdata-item-geturi    instead of    Uri.fromFile(photoFile)   use   FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", photoFile)

Comment: @ Amit Garg  mImageBitmap = rotateBitmap(mImageBitmap, 90);

Answer (score 22):

Capture photo + Choose from Gallery:

```
        a = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectImage();

            }

        });
    }
    private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
      String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      OutputStream outStream = null;
     // String temp = null;
        File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");
      if (file.exists()) {
       file.delete();
       file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");

      }

      try {
       outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
       outStream.flush();
       outStream.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
      }
      return file;
     }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
     private void selectImage() {



            final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };



            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");

            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))

                    {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                        //pic = f;

                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


                    }

                    else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))

                    {

                        Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);



                    }

                    else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                }

            });

            builder.show();

        }



        @Override

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    //h=0;
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());

                    for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                        if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {

                            f = temp;
                            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                           //pic = photo;
                            break;

                        }

                    }

                    try {

                        Bitmap bitmap;

                        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();



                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),

                                bitmapOptions); 



                        a.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




                        String path = android.os.Environment

                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()

                                + File.separator

                                + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                        //p = path;

                        f.delete();

                        OutputStream outFile = null;

                        File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                        try {

                            outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);

                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
    //pic=file;
                            outFile.flush();

                            outFile.close();


                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                } else if (requestCode == 2) {



                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                   // h=1;
    //imgui = selectedImage;
                    String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);

                    c.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);

                    c.close();

                    Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


                    Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");


                    a.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                }

            }
```

Comment: `ResultCode == 1` inside `ResultCode == RESULT_OK` ?

Comment: It's `requestCode==1`, helps identify who initiated the request.

Answer (score 19):

I know it's a quite old thread, but all these solutions are not completed and don't work on some devices when user rotates camera because data in onActivityResult is null. So here is solution which I have tested on lots of devices and haven't faced any problem so far.

First declare your Uri variable in your activity:

```
private Uri uriFilePath;
```

Then create your temporary folder for storing captured image and make intent for capturing image by camera:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    File mainDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFolder/tmp");
         if (!mainDirectory.exists())
             mainDirectory.mkdirs();

          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

          uriFilePath = Uri.fromFile(new File(mainDirectory, "IMG_" + calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
          intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFilePath);
          startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

And now here comes one of the most important things, you have to save your uriFilePath in onSaveInstanceState, because if you didn't do that and user rotated his device while using camera, your uri would be null.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     if (uriFilePath != null)
         outState.putString("uri_file_path", uriFilePath.toString());
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

After that you should always recover your uri in your onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         if (uriFilePath == null && savedInstanceState.getString("uri_file_path") != null) {
             uriFilePath = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("uri_file_path"));
         }
    } 
}
```

And here comes last part to get your Uri in onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         if (requestCode == 1) {
            String filePath = uriFilePath.getPath(); // Here is path of your captured image, so you can create bitmap from it, etc.
         }
    }
 }
```

P.S. Don't forget to add permissions for Camera and Ext. storage writing to your Manifest.

Comment: I am working with a FragmentDialog.  I tried to do this as you have.. I declared the Uri, then in a method "storeCapturedImage"- I put in the PackageManager code, then I added on onSaveInstanceState() - all of these before the onCreate.  Then in the onCreateDialog, I placed the 'recover your uri' code, and then the onActivityResult was placed just above the onCreate method... see next comment for what I put after the 'recover your uri' code

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.username_dialog, null);
ImageView profilePic = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_placeholder);
profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override public void onClick(View view) { storeCapturedImage();} }); builder.setView(dialogView);

Comment: I really wonder why the OS doesn't send you the uri in the intent inside of OnActivityResult. I hope there is a good reason, because carrying state around is always not a good thing to do IMO.

Comment: so what's the use of data in onActivityResult callback?

Answer (score 17):

**Here you can open camera or gallery and set the selected image into imageview**

```
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/YourDirectName";
private Context mContext;
private CircleImageView circleImageView;  // imageview
private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;
```

**Add permissions in manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**In onCreate()**

```
    requestMultiplePermissions(); // check permission 

    circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    circleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPictureDialog();
        }
    });
```

**Show options dialog box (to select image from camera or gallery)**

```
private void showPictureDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {"Select photo from gallery", "Capture photo from camera"};
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            choosePhotoFromGallary();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            takePhotoFromCamera();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    pictureDialog.show();
}
```

**Get photo from Gallery**

```
public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
}
```

**Get photo from Camera**

```
private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}
```

**Once the image is get selected or captured then ,**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                circleImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        circleImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        saveImage(thumbnail);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Now its time to store the picture**

```
public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {  // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::---&gt;" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Request permission**

```
    private void requestMultiplePermissions() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {  // check if all permissions are granted
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) { // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                        //openSettingsDialog();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).
            withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(DexterError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .onSameThread()
            .check();
}
```

Comment: startActivityForResult is deprecated

Answer (score 10):

You need to read up about the [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html).  (I think to do what you want, you'd have to save the current image to your app, do the select/delete there, and then recall the camera to try again, rather than doing the retry directly inside the camera.)

Answer (score 9):

Here is code I have used for Capturing and Saving Camera Image then display it to imageview. You can use according to your need.

You have to save Camera image to specific location then fetch from that location then convert it to byte-array.

Here is method for opening capturing camera image activity.

```
private static final int CAMERA_PHOTO = 111;
private Uri imageToUploadUri;

private void captureCameraImage() {
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "POST_IMAGE.jpg");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        imageToUploadUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO);
    }
```

then your onActivityResult() method should be like this.

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if(imageToUploadUri != null){
                    Uri selectedImage = imageToUploadUri;
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                    Bitmap reducedSizeBitmap = getBitmap(imageToUploadUri.getPath());
                    if(reducedSizeBitmap != null){
                        ImgPhoto.setImageBitmap(reducedSizeBitmap);
                        Button uploadImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadUserImageButton);
                          uploadImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error while capturing Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } 
        }
```

Here is getBitmap() method used in onActivityResult(). I have done all performance improvement that can be possible while getting camera capture image bitmap.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) >
                    IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                scale++;
            }
            Log.d("", "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

            Bitmap b = null;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            if (scale > 1) {
                scale--;
                // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
                // larger than target
                o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inSampleSize = scale;
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

                // resize to desired dimensions
                int height = b.getHeight();
                int width = b.getWidth();
                Log.d("", "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ", height: " + height);

                double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                        / (((double) width) / height));
                double x = (y / height) * width;

                Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x,
                        (int) y, true);
                b.recycle();
                b = scaledBitmap;

                System.gc();
            } else {
                b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            }
            in.close();

            Log.d("", "bitmap size - width: " + b.getWidth() + ", height: " +
                    b.getHeight());
            return b;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this and put captureImage() in the onClick from the onClickListener and not working.  I am working with a FragmentDialog... any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Capture photo from camera + pick image from gallery and set it into the background of layout or imageview. Here is sample code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class Post_activity extends Activity
    {
        final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
        final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 2;

        ImageView openCameraOrGalleryBtn,cancelBtn;
        LinearLayout backGroundImageLinearLayout;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedBundleInstance) {
            super.onCreate(savedBundleInstance);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up,0);
            setContentView(R.layout.post_activity);

            backGroundImageLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background_image_linear_layout);
            cancelBtn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cancel_icon);

            openCameraOrGalleryBtn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camera_icon);



            openCameraOrGalleryBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    selectImage();
                }
            });
            cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down,0);
                finish();
                }
            });

        }

    public void selectImage()
        {
             final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Post_activity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
                builder.setItems(options,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(options[which].equals("Take Photo"))
                        {
                            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
                        }
                        else if(options[which].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                        {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
                        }
                        else if(options[which].equals("Cancel"))
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });
                builder.show();
        }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent intent)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, intent);
            if(resultcode==RESULT_OK)
            {
                if(requestcode==TAKE_PICTURE)
                {
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
                    Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(photo);
                    backGroundImageLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

                }
                else if(requestcode==ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE)
                {
                    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                    String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                    c.close();
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(thumbnail);
                    backGroundImageLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);


                }
            }
        }

        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_down,0);
        }
    }

Add these permission in Androidmenifest.xml file

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: This is pretty old but I like the way you did this. When I choose from gallery, the image fails to display though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

I created a dialog with the option to choose Image from gallery or camera.
with a callback as

- Uri if the image is from the gallery
- String as a file path if the image is captured from the camera.
- Image as File the image chosen from camera needs to be uploaded on the internet as Multipart file data

At first we to define permission in AndroidManifest as we need to write external store while creating a file and reading images from gallery

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Create a file_paths xml in
app/src/main/res/xml/file_paths.xml

with path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Then we need to define file provier to generate Content uri to access file stored in external storage

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Dailog Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ImagePicker Dailog

```
public class ImagePicker extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
ImagePicker.GetImage getImage;
public ImagePicker(ImagePicker.GetImage getImage, boolean allowMultiple) {
    this.getImage = getImage;
}
File cameraImage;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_imagepicker, container, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.camera).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                captureFromCamera();
            }
        }
    });
    view.findViewById(R.id.gallery).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                startGallery();
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
public interface GetImage {
    void setGalleryImage(Uri imageUri);
    void setCameraImage(String filePath);
    void setImageFile(File file);
}@
Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == 1000) {
            Uri returnUri = data.getData();
            getImage.setGalleryImage(returnUri);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = null;
        }
        if(requestCode == 1002) {
            if(cameraImage != null) {
                getImage.setImageFile(cameraImage);
            }
            getImage.setCameraImage(cameraFilePath);
        }
    }
}
private void startGallery() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    cameraIntent.setType("image/*");
    if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000);
    }
}
private String cameraFilePath;
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, /* prefix */ ".jpg", /* suffix */ storageDir /* directory */ );
    cameraFilePath = "file://" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    cameraImage = image;
    return image;
}
private void captureFromCamera() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1002);
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Call in Activity or fragment like this
Define ImagePicker in Fragment/Activity

```
ImagePicker imagePicker;
```

Then call dailog on click of button

```
      imagePicker = new ImagePicker(new ImagePicker.GetImage() {
            @Override
            public void setGalleryImage(Uri imageUri) {

                Log.i("ImageURI", imageUri + "");

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                imagePreview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                cursor.close();

            }

            @Override
            public void setCameraImage(String filePath) {

                mediaPath =filePath;
                Glide.with(getContext()).load(filePath).into(imagePreview);

            }

            @Override
            public void setImageFile(File file) {

                cameraImage = file;

            }
        }, true);
        imagePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), imagePicker.getTag());
```

Answer (score 6):

As others have discussed, using `data.getExtras().get("data")` will just get the **low-quality thumbnail**.

The solution is to pass a location with your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent telling the camera where to store the full quality image.

The code is **Kotlin** and does not need any permissions.

---

```kotlin
val f = File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/imgShot")
val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "${packageName}.fileprovider", f)
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        .apply { putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI) }
startActivityForResult(intent, 1234)
```

Then handle the result after the picture was taken:

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 1234 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/imgShot").toString()
        )
        // use imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) or whatever
    }
}
```

---

You will also need to add an external FileProvider as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58908053/2111778). **`AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```xml
<manifest>
    <application>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provide_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Add a new file **`app/src/main/res/xml/provide_paths.xml`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Lastly you should replace `1234` with your own logic for keeping track of request code (usually an enum with a member such as `RequestCode.CAPTURE_IMAGE`)

Comment: Don't forgot to call `mkdirs()` before converting to uri. Otherwise won't work on targetSDK 33.

Answer (score 3):

In Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdfPic = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
                currentDateandTime = sdfPic.format(new Date()).replace(" ", "");
                File imagesFolder = new File(IMAGE_PATH, currentDateandTime);
                imagesFolder.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = IMAGE_NAME + n + IMAGE_FORMAT;
                File file = new File(imagesFolder, fname);
                outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                cameraIntent= new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_DATA);
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
           @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_DATA :
                final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 300;
                try {
                    // Bitmap bitmap;
                    File file = null;
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    BitmapFactory.Options opts;
                    int resizeScale;
                    Bitmap bmp;
                    file = new File(outputFileUri.getPath());
                    // This bit determines only the width/height of the
                    // bitmap
                    // without loading the contents
                    opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, opts);
                    fis.close();

                    // Find the correct scale value. It should be a power of
                    // 2
                    resizeScale = 1;

                    if (opts.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                            || opts.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                        resizeScale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE/ (double) Math.max(opts.outHeight, opts.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
                    }

                    // Load pre-scaled bitmap
                    opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    opts.inSampleSize = resizeScale;
                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, opts);
                    Bitmap getBitmapSize = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            getResources(), R.drawable.male);
                    image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            200,200));//(width,height);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    image.setRotation(90);
                    fis.close();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
                    imageByte = baos.toByteArray();
                    break;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

in layout.xml:

```
enter code here
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                            android:src="@drawable/XXXXXXX"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

in manifest.xml:

> ```
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom camera with thumbnail image.
You can look my [project](https://github.com/devcelebi/Kut-Camera).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete code:

```
package com.example.cameraa;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {




        Button btnTackPic;
        Uri photoPath;
        ImageView ivThumbnailPhoto;

        static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Get reference to views

            btnTackPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
            ivThumbnailPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);




     btnTackPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE); 
            }




    });

        } 

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {


                if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
                   ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                ivThumbnailPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            }
        }
}
```

Remember to add permissions for the camera too.

Answer (score 3):

### 2021 May, JAVA

after handling necessary Permissions described next to this post,
in manifest add:

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
....

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
....
```

where **${applicationId}** is app's package name , e.g. **my.app.com**.

In **res->xml->provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths>
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <files-path
    name="files"   path="." />
    <external-cache-path
      name="images" path="." />
 </paths>
```

in **Activity**:

```
private void onClickCaptureButton(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent_ = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent_.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile_ = null;
        try {
            photoFile_ = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if(photoFile_!=null){
            picturePath=photoFile_.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile_ != null) {
            Uri photoURI_ = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
               "my.app.com.fileprovider", photoFile_);
            takePictureIntent_.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI_);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent_, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

And three more moves:

```
...
private static String picturePath;
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;
...
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp_ = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new 
      Date());
    String imageFileName_ = "JPEG_" + timeStamp_ + "_";
    File storageDir_ = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image_ = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName_,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir_      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    picturePath= image_.getAbsolutePath();
    return image_;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK 
   ){

        try {
            File file_ = new File(picturePath);
            Uri uri_ = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "my.app.com.fileprovider", file_);
            rasm.setImageURI(uri_);
        } catch (/*IO*/Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("safar", picturePath);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        picturePath = savedInstanceState.getString("safar");
    }
 ....
}
```

Comment: startActivityForResult is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

`Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` gets a thumbnail from camera. There is an article about how to store a picture in external storage from camera.
[useful link](https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954)

Answer (score 2):

Please, follow this example with this implementation by using Kotlin and Andoirdx support:

```
button1.setOnClickListener{
        file = getPhotoFile()
        val uri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, "com.example.foto_2.filrprovider", file!!)
        captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)

        val camaraActivities: List<ResolveInfo> = applicationContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(captureImage, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)

        for (activity in camaraActivities) {
            applicationContext.grantUriPermission(activity.activityInfo.packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        }

        startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO)
    }
```

And the activity result:

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO) {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, "com.example.foto_2.filrprovider", file!!)
        applicationContext.revokeUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        imageView1.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            width = imageView1.width
            height = imageView1.height
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(getScaleBitmap(file!!.path , width , height))
        }
        if(width!=0&&height!=0){
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(getScaleBitmap(file!!.path , width , height))
        }else{
            val size = Point()
            this.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getSize(size)
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(getScaleBitmap(file!!.path , size.x , size.y))
        }

    }
```

You can get more detail in https://github.com/joelmmx/take_photo_kotlin.git

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to capture picture using your mobile camera.
   If you are using android having version higher than Lolipop, You should add the permission request also.

```
private void cameraIntent()
    {
          Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

@override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
     if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bad quality

From my experience if we use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ADD_PHOTO);
```

And handle in onActivityResult() with

```
Bitmap thumbnail= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

It will give you thumbnail only and of course have a bad quality.

## Nice quality

You can show camera and save your image file in public directory, example in Document directory

Use this in your **onClick()**

```
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) +
                File.separator + "your_image_name.jpeg";
Intent i =new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageFile = new File(imagePath );
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_ADD_PHOTO);
```

And in **onActivityResult()**

```
Bitmap imageBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageBitmap1, 0, 0, imageBitmap1.getWidth(), imageBitmap1.getHeight(), matrix, true);
binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

I use postRotate() because in my code, image result rotate to left so I need to rotate it 90

Answer (score 0):

Capture Image For Kotlin

Step 1 : Add Camera Permission

Step 2 : Reusable Kotlin Extension Function Usage

```
fun Activity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE: Int = 313, photoFileCallback: (file: File) -> Unit = {}) {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    null
                }
    
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                photoFile?.also {
                    photoFileCallback(it)
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            this,
                            packageName,
                            it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                }
            }
        }
```